# conversion of mongodb into php with 'and'

Tags: php, mongodb

I have long query on mongodb. I want to write that in php
The query looks like

```
"department":"xxx","rank":"xxx",
 $and:[{"emails.email" :{$ne : ""}},{"emails.email":{$ne:null}}];
```

I want to convert into php.

"department"=>$xxx,"rank"=>$xxx..??
for converting 'and' I cant come up. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to work with the $ modifiers is to use single quotes as seen below.  It's close on the syntax however you will want to double check it as I'm certain there may have been a missed bracket.

```
array(
  'department'=>'', 
  'rank=>'', 
  '$and'=>array(
     'emails.email'=>array('$ne'=>''), 
     'emails.email'=>array('$ne'=>NULL)
  )
);
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can commit the query that @Frederico wrote however this query could do with some optimisation. Here is a suggestion:

```
array(
    'department' => '',
    'rank' => '',
    'emails.email' => array('$nin' => array('', null))
)
```

That will do the job just as good without the `$and` and the two separate `$ne`.